# Is the cursor suposed to do this?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-cursor

I didn't see this anywhere before,[image] but the 3d cursor is doing something odd, and i didnt know where to post it

look at the top please.

Thank you.

Comment: Nothing strange. If you move the cursor and move the view it makes sense that the cursor moves with it, if that is what you are asking. The cursor is not 2D but part of the three-dimensional environment.

Comment: i understand what you're saying, but what i'm talking about is that the red and white pattern is spinning (zoom in to see better)

Comment: What issues is it causing?